# Pygame icon & caption dont update. What is the problem?

Tags: python, pygame, icons, caption

in my code, the caption and icon update dont work. I have pygame 1.9.6, python 3.8 and the png files are 32.32. I have the code which is:

```
import pygame   
pygame.init()  
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600)   
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")    
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')    
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

playerImg = pygame.image.load('player.png')    
playerX = 370    
playerY = 480     
def player():   
    screen.blit(playerImg,(playerX,playerY))

running = True   
while running:
   
colour = (255, 0, 0)    
    screen.fill(colour)    
    for event in pygame.event.get():        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:     
            running = False     
    
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is missing a `)`:

<s>`screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600)`</s>

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
```

---

You have to update the display in the main application loop instead of after the loop. Correct the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html):

```
while running:
    # [...]

    #-->| INDENTATION
    pygame.display.update()
```

---

See [`pygame.display.set_icon()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_icon):

> [...] Some systems do not allow the window icon to change after it has been shown. This function can be called before `pygame.display.set_mode()` to create the icon before the display mode is set.

Set the icon before `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))`:

```py
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")    
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')    
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
```

---

Working code:

```py
import pygame   
pygame.init()  

pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")    
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')    
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))   

playerImg = pygame.image.load('player.png')    
playerX = 370    
playerY = 480     
def player():   
    screen.blit(playerImg,(playerX,playerY))

running = True   
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:     
            running = False     
    
    colour = (255, 0, 0)    
    screen.fill(colour)    
    player()    
    pygame.display.update()
```